# Execute functions of external contracts through chainlink automation contracts

Tags: contract-development, chainlink, out-of-gas, uniswapv3

I have two contracts. One is a contract that implements chainlink to obtain off-chain data. Part of its code is

```
  function requestConfig() public returns (bytes32 id) {
     Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
         jobId,
         address(this),
         this.fulfill.selector
     );
     req.add(
        "get",
        "https://api.xxxx.info/v1/api/datafeed/get?parameters=data"
     );
     req.add("path", "data");
     return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
  }
  function getPositionData() external view returns(uint256[] memory) {
     return positionData;
  }

  function fulfill(
     bytes32 _requestId,
     string memory _dataType
  ) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
     require(positionAddress != address(0),"position address error");
     IAutoPosition(positionAddress).mintNewPosition(1,1);
  }
```

The `fulfill` function will call the `mintNewPosition` function of another contract after receiving the data. Its function is to cast uniswap v3 position. Part of the code is

```
function mintNewPosition(uint256 amount0In,uint256 amount1In) external returns (
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint128 liquidity,
        uint256 amount0,
        uint256 amount1
    ) {
            
    uint256 amount0ToMint = amount0In * 1e18;
    uint256 amount1ToMint = amount1In * 1e18;
    int24 tickLowerMint = -887220;
    int24 tickUpperMint = 887220;

    TransferHelper.safeApprove(UNI, address(nonfungiblePositionManager), amount0ToMint);
    TransferHelper.safeApprove(WETH, address(nonfungiblePositionManager), amount1ToMint);
    
    INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams memory params =
        INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
            token0: UNI,
            token1: WETH,
            fee: poolFee,
            tickLower: tickLowerMint,
            tickUpper: tickUpperMint,
            amount0Desired: amount0ToMint,
            amount1Desired: amount1ToMint,
            amount0Min: 0,
            amount1Min: 0,
            recipient: address(this),
            deadline: block.timestamp
        });
    (tokenId, liquidity, amount0, amount1) = nonfungiblePositionManager.mint(params);

}
```

An error occurred when executing `IAutoPosition(positionAddress).mintNewPosition(1,1);`. I used tenderly to check the error and he told me `out of gas`. I made sure that there were enough links in my first contract and in the second contract. With enough UNI and WETH, I tried many times and this is one of the transactions and it happened on goerli network
`0x172a1f5199846b95c978d28cfe6f10665f88dd44b43a8be40fa7df4e10fa0767`
Please help me, any thanks

Comment: Hi Leo
Out of gas means out of the native token on the chain you're running the contract on,  not LINK, UNI or WETH.  

Also you should consider Chainlink Functions(https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions) instead of Chainlink AnyAPI. Much, much faster, flexible and more powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, make sure token0 and token1 are in the same order as the token0 and token1 of the pool address